# Issue with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to write a regex where a string has
(9 characters) and start with either "g" or "r"
and then are all numbers afterward.

I have written this but it does not work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String id= "g57895452";
    String pattern = "/^g([0-9]+){8}$/";
    if (id.matches(pattern)) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of your `if` you can simply use `System.out.println(id.matches(pattern))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corrected re:

```
"^[gr]([0-9]{8})$"
```

You need not `+` when you already has `{8}`.

Also you don't need `()` when you don't want to use the group further in the code.

```
"^[gr][0-9]{8}$"
```

Comment: it alwasy gives false for the given id,it is not returning true

Comment: @JaneRaj: Remove the slashes please

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `/` from start and end of your regex pattern, It will work.

Comment: True, but that's not the only problem.